# How to make a discord bot PYTHON command that saves a crypto address when submited by a user and can be displayed at any time with a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So basically I need the command to be something like this,

`-submitaddress` (sent by user)

`enter your address here` (sent by the bot)

and after that the bot saves the address with their username as reference.

When the user does `-showaddress` the bot would display the address.

I'm not sure how to make this, it has to be in discord.py because that's what I used for all my other commands. It would be great if someone could make a basic version of this for me or let me know where to look so I can make it myself. I run a crypto project, I'm willing to give some of our crypto for free to anyone who helps me out

Comment: isnt that eazy?

Comment: Store the information in a JSON or database. Something like: `ctx.author.id, address` and then make a command that reads out the entry for `ctx.author.id` in your database/JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you're looking for

```py
@bot.command()
async def submitaddress(ctx):
    # Since bot asks the user the address seperately we don't need to accept any arguments.
    await ctx.send("Enter your address here")
    msg = await bot.wait_for(
        "message",
        check=lambda msg: msg.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
        and msg.author.id == ctx.author.id,
    )
    # msg.content now contains the address
    with open("data.json") as r:
        data = json.load(r)
    with open("data.json", "w+") as w:
        data[str(ctx.author.id)] = msg.content
        w.write(json.dumps(data))
    await ctx.send("Successfully assigned address")


@bot.command()
async def showaddress(ctx):
    # OP of the stack post did not mention if this should take any arguments
    # So this doesn't take args and just displays invoke user's address
    with open("data.json") as r:
        data = json.load(r)
    await ctx.send("Address:\n{}".format(data[str(ctx.author.id)]))
```

Which would result in :
[image: result]
(you could of course style it later)

Be sure to create a file named `data.json` in the directory that the python file is in or provide a full path when accessing the file within the code. The contents of the JSON file should be `{}` when creating it.

I personally would recommend using the Postgres database here if you are doing anything large-scale.

Here's the full code that was used to create the above result though :

```py
import discord
import os
import json
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-", case_insensitive=True, help_command=None)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {bot.user}")


@bot.command()
async def submitaddress(ctx):
    # Since bot asks the user the address seperately we don't need to accept any arguments.
    await ctx.send("Enter your address here")
    msg = await bot.wait_for(
        "message",
        check=lambda msg: msg.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
        and msg.author.id == ctx.author.id,
    )
    # msg.content now contains the address
    # we write it to an json file, I recommend using a postgres db for this if this is for serious use
    with open("data.json") as r:
        data = json.load(r)
    with open("data.json", "w+") as w:
        data[str(ctx.author.id)] = msg.content
        w.write(json.dumps(data))
    await ctx.send("Successfully assigned address")


@bot.command()
async def showaddress(ctx):
    # OP of the stack post did not mention if this should take any arguments
    # So this doesn't take args and just displays invoke user's address
    with open("data.json") as r:
        data = json.load(r)
    await ctx.send("Address:\n{}".format(data[str(ctx.author.id)]))


bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```